# Pass extended class of an abstract class as a parameter in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, abstract-class, flutter-web

I am trying to build a website using flutter but I can't figure out.
This is an abstract class.

```
abstract class TableBaseClass {
  int getPage(BuildContext context);
  void setPage(int val,BuildContext context);
  int getPagination();
  void setPagination(String val,BuildContext context);
  void setSearch(String val,BuildContext context);
  String getSearch();
  dynamic getData();
  List getHeaders();
  List getBodyFields();
  void refresh(BuildContext context);
  void setSort(String header);
  void setOrder(String order,BuildContext context);
  String getOrder();
}
```

And this class is extending it.

```
class Objects extends TableBaseClass with ChangeNotifier {
```

and this widget takes the abstract class as a parameter.

```
class TableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final TableBaseClass provider;
  final String menuButton;

  const TableWidget(this.provider,this.menuButton, {super.key});
```

but when I pass the Objects class
`TableWidget(Objects,menuButton)`
It gives error `The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TableBaseClass'.`

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Why did you call your class Objects? [Object is the base class for all dart objects](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Object-class.html). Also, shouldn't your provider be of type Objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you're simply trying to pass a Type, not an instance of the `TableBaseClass` class, you didn't call the class constructor, see this:

```
print(TableBaseClass); // this is a type, 
print(TableBaseClass.runtimeType); // Type
```

but with `()`, you're creating an instance of that class:

```
print(TableBaseClass()); // this is an instance of TableBaseClass 
print(TableBaseClass().runtimeType); // TableBaseClass
```